# Android AlertDialog using Intents to finish Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to finish my Activities when the user selects the quit option in an `AlertDialog` within another class. However, when I try to use the `getApplicationContext()` I get this error

```
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
```

and the error

```
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
```

for the `StartActivity(intent)`. Any advice will be great. Thanks

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setTitle("End Option ")
.setMessage("Continue ?")
.setPositiveButton("Quit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
}).setNegativeButton("Retry",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

}}).show();
```

Comment: pass context instead of getApplicationContext() in intent parameter .

Comment: That fixed the getApplicationContext(), but not the startActivity(intent) error. Thanks

Comment: context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Hi @Amit625 did you try my answer? Is it working?

Comment: @Fllo sorry I tried to rate the answer but I am not allowed. And yes your answer worked. Thank you very much

Comment: @Amit625 It was just to know, but rather than rate the answer you could just accept it - the check mark (below the arrow) allows you to accept an answer which worked (whatever the rating). Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the intent into a method like,

```
 public void anotheractivity()
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
 startActivity(intent);  


}
```

and call them from alert box,

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
   .setTitle("End Option ")
  .setMessage("Continue ?")
  .setPositiveButton("Quit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
     //call the method here
        anotheractivity();
     }).setNegativeButton("Retry",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

        }}).create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the `Activity` to start another one, and pass the `Context` just as you set it above in your `Builder` with the **content** variable:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

You can also get the context by the `getContext` method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
getContext().startActivity(i);
```